# How to create a 3 X 3 Matrix will all ones in it using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learner , bit stuck with it
Not getting how do I create below 3 X 3 matrix will all 1 ones in it

```
  1 , 1 , 1
  1 , 1 , 1
  1 , 1 , 1
```

**My code :**

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.ones(np.full(1)).reshape(3,3)
arr
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
>>> np.ones((3,3))
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])

>>> np.ones((3,3)).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

if You want `int`

```
>>> np.ones((3,3), dtype='int')
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want use `reshape()`:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.ones(9).reshape(3,3)
```

or directly:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.ones(shape=(3,3))
```

or from another matrix:

```
import numpy as np
arr1=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
arr2=np.ones_like(arr1)
```

read documentations ([link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html))

> shape: Shape of the new array, e.g., (2, 3) or 2.

if you want `1` instead of `1.` set argumant `dtype = int`

> dtype: The desired data-type for the array The default, None, means

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-
You need to use  **np.ones method**

```
import numpy as np 
m = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=float) 
print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import numpy as np
np.ones((3,3))
```